# Countdown with time() PHP and moment.js

Tags: javascript, php, momentjs

I made code to countdown based on the result of a current timestamp that adds up to five minutes, and I can't get the script to display the countdown from that timestamp. The code complete:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var duration = moment.duration(1646486515 * 1000, 'milliseconds');
            var interval = 1000;
            setInterval(function(){
                duration = moment.duration(duration.asMilliseconds() - interval, 'milliseconds');
                $('#time').text(moment(duration.asMilliseconds()).format('h:mm:ss'));
                if(duration.asSeconds() <=0) {
                    window.location.replace(window.location.pathname + window.location.search + window.location.hash);
                }
            }, interval);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center><p><h1>Hello, world!</h1></p></center>
        <div class="container mb-2 my-2">
            <div class="p-3 shadow-sm">
                result of code: <span id="time" class="countdown">--:--</span>
                <?php
                    echo '<br />NOW:'.time().'<br>+5 minutes: '.time()+300;
                ?>
                <br />
                What i want is: 00:04:59
            </div>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

The result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNBND.png

if you give "+5 minutes", that is the sum of time() function + 300 seconds (5 minutes), you will have, for example, the date now + 5 minutes on future, but in timestamp. The intention here, is that script count 00:05:00 starting of time() now.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "nothing works" - what exactly happens when you run the code you've shown?

Comment: Since `moment.duration()` allows you to specify the units, there's no need to convert. Just specify `seconds` as the unit and it will handle it for you.

Comment: @IMSoP, this code informed on question is functional. But, as sayed on my question the code no work with time minutes countdown with base on result of function "Time()". 300 seconds is equal to 5 minutes. Instead of the counter showing 5 minutes counting down, it shows 9 hours. And... Barmar, i tried that way, and it didn't work. I did not enter the multiplication of the value. I just left the timestamp result, and it still doesn't pass. Thanks :)

Comment: Please click [edit] underneath the question, and show us the full code that you're running, explain what is happening, and what you expected to happen instead. Also *remove* any parts that are *not* relevant to the question - if the countdown part is working fine, we don't need to see it, only the part that is showing the "wrong" time.

Comment: Ok, the question is reformuled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look carefully at this line:

```
var duration = moment.duration(1646486515 * 1000, 'milliseconds');
```

How many minutes are there in 1646486515 seconds? A lot more than five! In fact, it is somewhere over 52 **years**, but when you format it you aren't showing the years, months, and days, only the remaining hours, minutes, and seconds.

That's because `time()` is returning you a representation of a *point in time*, based on the number of seconds elapsed since midnight UTC, 1st January 1970.

In order to get the duration between that point in time and another point in time, you need to compare them. The simplest way to do that is to substract one from another. For instance, `1646486815 - 1646486515` gives you `300`, representing a duration of 300 seconds between those two points in time.

In your example, you know the duration is 300 seconds, so could just write that:

```
var duration = moment.duration(300 * 1000, 'milliseconds');
```

Or more simply:

```
var duration = moment.duration(300, 'seconds');
```

A second problem is on this line:

```
$('#time').text(moment(duration.asMilliseconds()).format('h:mm:ss'));
```

Here, we take a *duration*, and use it to create a "moment", that is a specific point in time; but what point in time, and why? What we actually wanted was to format it, because the duration type doesn't have a `format` method, but it has methods to get hours, minutes, and seconds, so we can just write that ourselves:

```
var duration = moment.duration(300, 'seconds');
formattedDuration = duration.hours() + ':' + String(duration.minutes()).padStart(2, '0') + ':' + String(duration.seconds()).padStart(2, '0');
$('#time').text(formattedDuration);
```

The key here is to look at each piece in turn, not get caught up trying to put the pieces together until we have things working. Once we know we can create a duration based on a number of seconds, and format that duration, we can add in the PHP to decide how many seconds to start with. Once we have that working, we can add in the part that counts that duration down, and then the part that does something extra once it reaches zero.

Comment: before edit my question, i cited about subtract on value by other, and obtain 300 as you explained, but, if you test the code actual and subtract by other value with five minutes on future, the result of code is same thing. If you did this: https://i.imgur.com/HdzSQOM.png the result is this: https://i.imgur.com/06wEFOQ.png but, i wanted explore more the code, and discover that the result of time()+300 is equal a the date with UTC different of "moment.js", that give me the date of PC. Even using "new Date().getTime()" to get the date in timestamp instead of PHP, is same thing.

Comment: I tried many ways, and none worked. Countdown this way doesn't work... I tried using timestamp, because there can be a passage of time between one date and another, but apparently that doesn't work with script. Thanks a lot by your help.

Comment: @RobsonBarros The key to debugging is always to break things down, not to add more guesswork. Simply the code, look at smaller pieces, and so on. So forget about PHP; forget about where the number of seconds is ultimately going to come from, forget about the countdown. Write some code that takes the number 300, hard-coded, and formats it to say "5:00" because it's 5 minutes. Then start building back up again, one step at a time, and stop *as soon as it doesn't look right*.

Comment: I've added another section at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my problem with another idea. Maybe if you are searching for answers, this will help you.

First, if you use function "time()" of PHP with + 5 minutes, transform to a datetime string with this function:

```
date('Y-m-d H:m:s', $row['time_stamp'])
```

with this, the result is a date formatted: 2022-03-05 12:00:00 (already with 5 minutes included).

Then, download the script from here: http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html After install, use the script of documentation and define a timezone.

The code final code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mckamey/countdownjs/master/countdown.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var timesZone = moment.tz("<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$get['time_zone']); ?>","America/Sao_Paulo");
            $("#timer").countdown(timesZone.toDate(), function(event) {
                $(this).text(event.strftime('%H:%M:%S'));
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center><p><h1>Hello, world!</h1></p></center>
        <div class="container mb-2 my-2">
            <div class="p-3 shadow-sm">
                result of code: <span id="timer" class="countdown">--:--</span>
                <?php
                    $newTime = time()+300;
                    echo '<br />NOW:'.time().'<br>+5 minutes: '.$newTime.'<br />New time date: '. date('Y-m-d H:s:i',time());
                ?>
                <br />
                What i want is: 00:04:59
            </div>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I understand, I replied with an alternative that solves the question in case someone didn't understand 100% your answer.

Comment: You're right, sorry, that was unnecessarily harsh. If you're looking to just get it done, using someone else's code is fine. If you're interested in becoming a better programmer, though, taking the time to debug your code and understand where you went wrong is extremely valuable.

Comment: That's why I marked it as resolved when you replied before I posted my alternative. Thanks a lot IMSoP :)